# cant compile pjsip for iOS because of fatal error

Tags: ios, compilation, fatal-error, pjsip

I try to improve an App using an old version of pjsip. Since in this version the loudspeaker won't work anymore, I wanted to update pjsip.

Since I found no tutorial how to simply update the pjsip you are using I tried to download and compile the newest version.

But the compiling allways stopps with this exception:

```
pjmedia-audiodev/errno.c23:13: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
```

What could cause this problem?
I was following this guide:

https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

What made me also a bit curious is that in the file "config_site.h" already were alot of defines. Do I still need them while the guid says it should have thoose two lines:

```
#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
```

When I am ready with compiling, would I be able to simply overwrite the files the app I'm working on useses with the files I just compiled?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the **Portaudio** is not installed on your system.

You can get it from Macports or Homebrew with the following commands:

- sudo port install portaudio

or

- sudo brew install portaudio

About your second question for the defines in the "config_site.h" file, it's depend of the application it self, usually the mentioned settings are enough but is also possible that for your case additional parameters are needed, like enabling video or additional codecs etc.